# How to auto fill empty cells in Google sheets only if data is found in another column?

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a script or macro to auto fill empty cells with "-" only if data is found in another column of the same row in Google sheets.

I know there is a way to Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+f to replace all blanks "^\s*$" with "-", but I am trying to make the document more user friendly for the users, any suggestions?

Comment: You need a Google Apps Script and an [`onEdit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).

Answer (score 0):

try in row 1 in any column after A column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A="";;"-"))
```